# Patchwork doesn't recognize plots with ggMargnial distribution elements

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

##### Trying to display 2 plots with **ggMarginal** but the plots are not recognized as such.

I'm pasting a simplified version of the code below where:

- *Before* adding the ggMarginal element Patchwork displays ggplots side by side as expected
- *After* adding marginal distributions with ggMarginal, Patchwork doesn't seem to recognize the the plot any more. The error message that I get is the following:

```r
p1m + p2m
#> Error in p1m + p2m: non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Here's the code I'm running:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggExtra)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 1')

p1m <- ggMarginal(p1,
                 type = "density",
                 size = 3)

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(hp, wt, colour = mpg)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 3')

p2m <- ggMarginal(p2,
                 type = "density",
                 size = 3)

p1+p2



p1m + p2m
#> Error in p1m + p2m: non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

<sup>Created on 2021-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether there is an easy option to make `patchwork` work with objects of class `ggMarginal`.

Another option to add side plots would be to make use of the `ggside` package which works fine with `patchwork`. One drawback of `ggside` is that (to the best of my knowledge) as of the moment it does not offer any options to style the side plots, i.e. it will inherit the style of the main plot's `theme`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggside)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'ggside':
#>   method from   
#>   +.gg   ggplot2
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_xsidedensity(aes(y = after_stat(density)), position = "stack") +
  geom_ysidedensity(aes(x = after_stat(density)), position = "stack") +
  ggtitle('Plot 1')  +
  theme(ggside.panel.scale = .5)

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt, colour = mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_xsidedensity(aes(y = after_stat(density)), position = "stack") +
  geom_ysidedensity(aes(x = after_stat(density)), position = "stack") +
  ggtitle('Plot 3') +
  theme(ggside.panel.scale = .5,)

p1 + p2
```

[image]

A second but cumbersome option would be to make the marginal plots via `ggplot2` too and glue all together using `patchwork`:

```r
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 1')

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp, colour = mpg)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 3')

p1ma <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_density(aes(mpg)) + 
  theme_void()

p1mb <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_density(aes(y = disp)) + 
  theme_void()

wrap_plots(list(p1ma, plot_spacer(), p1ma, plot_spacer(), p1, p1mb, p2, p1mb), 
           widths = c(2, 1, 2, 1), heights = c(1, 2),
           ncol = 4, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE) &
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! The [dev branch of `ggside`](https://github.com/jtlandis/ggside/tree/dev) currently supports styling of the side panel themes aside from the main panels. Just thought I'd put this out there if it matters to the OP

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your marginal plots in `patchwork::wrap_elements()`

```
patchwork::wrap_elements(p1m) + patchwork::wrap_elements(p2m)
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution out there. Can't understand why it doesn't get more upvotes! Thank you!