# Properly size multiple ggExtraPlot objects after calling ggMarginal in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot, grob, patchwork

I want to create a facet-like effect with `ggExtra::ggMarginal` plots. This is [not yet directly possible](https://github.com/daattali/ggExtra/issues/28), so I tried to use `patchwork::wrap_plots`, `cowplot::plot_grid`, and `egg::ggarrange` to do it myself. I have everything properly developed—except for the plot sizing. `patchwork` and `egg` make the *panels* of *`ggplot`* objects the same size, but this behavior does not apply to the `ggExtraPlot` objects that `ggMarginal` creates.

For example, consider the following `patchwork` of `ggplot`s (code below):
[image: four ggplots correctly sized]

But once I add the marginal densities, the arrangement looks like this:
[image: four ggplots incorrectly sized]

As you can see, the *panels* of each plot are no longer equally sized; rather, the entire objects are. I want the panel sizes of each `ggplot` in the second plot to be the same, as in the first plot.

Attempted solutions:

- I tried to determine the width and height of the axes relative to the panel, because then I could use the `widths` and `heights` arguments in `wrap_plot` to set proper relative sizes of the `ggMarginal`-ized objects; unfortunately, I spent many hours unsuccessfully digging through the `ggplotGrob` output. For instance, I used `grid::convertWidth(sum(ggplotGrob(p1)$widths), "in", TRUE)` and `grid::convertWidth(sum(ggplotGrob(p2)$widths), "in", TRUE)` to attempt to calculate the widths of the plots in inches (`p1` has a y-axis, `p2` doesn't), but the results were vastly different: 0.87 and 0.19. It didn't make sense to me that simply removing the axis title, text, and ticks would so heavily decrease the width. Certainly setting the relative widths at around 4.5 and 1 wouldn't generate the proper `patchwork` plot!
- I tried to use `patchwork::get_dim` and `patchwork::set_dim` to manually set the area for each subplot (using `patchwork::area`) but couldn't figure it out.
- I also tried to create the patchwork first and then apply `ggMarginal` to each plot in the patchwork, but this didn't work.

I would appreciate advice on guaranteeing equal panel sizes for the four plots, ideally without relying on the actual size (i.e., in pixels) of the components. It would be awesome to see `ggMarginal` allow faceting and to see `patchwork` extend beyond simple `ggplot` objects!

```
b <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "some\nlines",
       y = "many\nnew\nlines")

p1 <-  b +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
p1m <- ggExtra::ggMarginal(p1, margins = "y")

p2 <- b +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
p2m <- ggExtra::ggMarginal(p2, margins = "y")

p3 <- b
p3m <- ggExtra::ggMarginal(p3, margins = "y")

p4 <- b +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
p4m <- ggExtra::ggMarginal(p4, margins = "y")

patchwork::wrap_plots(p1, p2, p3, p4, nrow = 2)      # this looks great!
patchwork::wrap_plots(p1m, p2m, p3m, p4m, nrow = 2)  # this doesn't :(
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of relying on `ggMarginal` one option would be to manually create your density plots and glue both your main and the density plots together using `patchwork`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

dp <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(y = mpg)) +
  geom_density() +
  theme_void()

list(p1, dp, p2, dp, p3, dp, p4, dp) |> 
  wrap_plots(nrow = 2, widths = c(5, 1, 5, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: That would certainly work! I’ll leave the question open for just a few days to see if anyone has a more general method. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @PrayagGordy. Yeah. Sure. Just in case: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69507674/patchwork-doesnt-recognize-plots-with-ggmargnial-distribution-elements/69509320#69509320) related post (and answer by me) with another option using `ggside`.